# Solving a characteristic equation of a differential equation of the 4th order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

My DE equation looks like this:

$y^{(3)}+y^{(2)}+34y^{(1)}+40y=xe^{-4x}+2e^{-3x}cos(x)$

I'm having trouble solving for the characteristic equation

$r^4+r^3+34r^2+40r=0$

I got it down to    $r(r^3+r^2+34r+40)=0$ but I'm not sure how to factor it any further to find real zeros. I guess this is more of an algebra type ordeal, but I'm stumped.

Comment: $y^{(3)}+y^{(2)}+34y^{(1)}+40y=xe^{-4x}+2e^{-3x}cos(x)$ is of the third order. Why do you entitle your question with "of the fourth order" ?

Answer (score 0):

I bet that your equation is not $y^{(3)}+y^{(2)}+34y^{(1)}+40y=xe^{-4x}+2e^{-3x}cos(x)$, but is :
$$y^{(3)}+10y^{(2)}+34y^{(1)}+40y=xe^{-4x}+2e^{-3x}cos(x)$$
Hit : $r^3+10r^2+34r+40=(r+4)(r+3+i)(r+3-i)$

Do you understand the reason of the guess ?